# how to find the distribution of the least square estimator $\beta$?

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-inference, estimation, linear-regression

i'm solving a problem that involve a linear model, and i'm trying to get the distribution of the least square estimator $\beta$.

i found in a book that:

> $\widehat{\beta}\sim N_{p}(\beta, (X^{\prime}X)^{-}\sigma^{2})$. but how can i get the distributions to $\beta_{i}$?.

in my case, the matrix $(X^{\prime}X)^{-}$, i found was:

$$ \frac 1 \alpha
\begin{bmatrix} 
 \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 &  -\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \\
  &  \\
 -\sum_{i=1}^N x_i & N\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $\alpha= N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2- \left[ \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right]^2$
and i'm looking for the distribution of $\beta_1, \beta_2$.

Comment: For your model you have $N$ observations, the intercept is $\beta_1$, and the slope is $\beta_2$, correct? Also your inverse matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$ should have a factor $$\frac1{N\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2}$$ in front of it.

Comment: yes, sorry you are right. i have edited. But i'm still confuse cuz $\beta$ is a vector and  $(X^{\prime}X)^{-} \sigma^{2}$ is a matrix. so what is the variance of $\beta$'s.

Answer (score 1):

The result that you found
$$
\hat\beta\sim N_p(\beta, (X'X)^{-1}\sigma^2)\tag{*}
$$ allows you to read off the solution to your problem. If your model is
$$Y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2x_i+\varepsilon_i,\qquad i=1,\ldots,N,
$$
then interpret the assertion (*) to mean that the joint distribution of $(\hat\beta_1,\hat\beta_2)$ is bivariate normal ($p=2$) with mean $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$ and covariance matrix $(X'X)^{-1}\sigma^2$. So the marginal distribution of $\hat\beta_1$ is normal with mean $\beta_1$ and variance equal to the $(1,1)$ entry of the covariance matrix, which is
$$
\frac{\sigma^2}{N\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2}\sum x_i^2=\sigma^2\frac{\sum x_i^2}{N\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2}.\tag1
$$
Similarly the distribution of $\hat\beta_2$ is normal with mean $\beta_2$ and variance equal to the $(2,2)$ entry of the covariance matrix, which is
$$
\frac{\sigma^2}{N\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2}N=\sigma^2\frac{N}{N\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2}.\tag2
$$
In (1) and (2), the denominator can be rewritten $N\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2$.

If your model is
$$
Y_i = \theta x_i + \varepsilon_i,\qquad i=1,\ldots,N,
$$
then the design matrix $X$ is a column $[x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_N]'$ so $X'X=\sum x_i^2$ and the result (*) says that the estimator $\hat\theta$ is normal with mean $\theta$ and variance $\displaystyle\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum x_i^2}.$

Comment: @JohanR Please see my edit. It is fine to define the $x_i=t_i^2/2$ as you have done, assuming the $t_i$'s are nonrandom. Your model is now $Y_i=\theta t_i+\varepsilon_i$ with no intercept. It has only one parameter.

Comment: thank you, for your help. mmm i have a a little doubt in my case the linear model is of the form Yi=t2i/2θ+εi and i took xi=t2i/2, and to write the model as a canonical linear model i took Θ′=[0,θ], so β0=0,β1=θ, but even in this case has sense to say that Var(θ)=Nσ2α?. but what about Var(β0)?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\widehat \beta_1 = \big[ 1, 0\big] \widehat\beta.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
& \operatorname E\left(\widehat\beta_1\right) = \big[1,0\big]\operatorname E \left( \widehat\beta \right) = \big[1,0\big]\beta = \beta_1. \\[10pt]
& \operatorname{var}\left(\widehat\beta_1\right) = \operatorname{var}\left( \big[1,0\big] \widehat\beta \right) = \big[1,0\big]\Big( \operatorname{var}\left(\widehat\beta\right) \Big) \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] \\[10pt]
= {} & \sigma^2 \big[1,0\big] \left( \frac 1 \alpha
\begin{bmatrix} 
 \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 &  -\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \\
  &  \\
 -\sum_{i=1}^N x_i & N\\
\end{bmatrix} \right) \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] = \cdots
\end{align}
That gives you the expected value and the variance. And if $\widehat\beta$ is bivariate normal then a linear combination of its components with constant (i.e. non-random) coefficients is univariate normal.

And similarly for $\widehat\beta_2.$